# HTML textarea with image upload

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm currently in need of develop a website that allow user to input information and images into a `<textarea>` then save to database. Those data will be displayed in another page.

I though of using AJAX to upload file then append the `<img>` to `<textarea>`. But this approach will produce SQL injection security threat.

So I need an advice on how to achieve this but still can get rid of SQL injection.

Comment: suggestion is same as to all other how to prevent sql injection, and that is to use prepared statements and parameterized queries.

Comment: This is a server-side problem. Which programming language are you using there?

Comment: @Juhana I'm using MVC3 with C#

Comment: @BojanKovacevic Thank for your advice, and you're right. Prepared statements and Parameterized queries can get rid of SQL injection, but what make me worry is can i display the image properly just by query it? Like select it and put the result into a div, and the image will display properly

Answer (score 2):

When the user uploads an image, just do the following and you will be safe to append the image HTML to the textarea:

1. Is the user upload a valid JPG/GIF/PNG/x image? (Use image libraries to verify that.)
2. Rename the image to something "safe" like a CRC32 of its contents + the current time in microseconds so the file name is innocuous.
3. Put the image with its new name in a location that can be served.

Answer (score 1):

you'll find you cant upload files using ajax - you will want to find a plugin for that. I'd reccomend looking at https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki - although it may have too many features. Theres even an mvc3 example for it! https://github.com/maxpavlov/jQuery-File-Upload.MVC3

After you upload the image, I suppose you can trigger another ajax event to retrieve the image and then display it in a div next to the text area.

As far as security issues, I've been told allowing a user to upload a file is inherently insecure. see https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Security for more details.

My apologies for the excess links. Also, if you're storing many, many files with infrequent access, you may want to consider saving the files to disk. ie.  write them to a network location and store the filename in a table (save the file on disk with a GUID).

ie. Table UserFileLocations

PK   |   UserFileName   |        DiskID

1..n |  tree.jpg    |  //ServerPath/Folder/103c-aa34-0ac2-01cd 
...

Comment: Nice plugin, Sir! Thanks a lot for your help. I'll give it a try